# Pandas For Loop with Two Variables

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column in a dataframe based on the values in two other columns:

```
names_df['Surname'] = [
    'MISSING' if i != '' and j == '' else j 
    for i, j in names_df['Name Entry 1'], names_df['Name Entry 2']
]
```

However I am getting an invalid syntax error but I don't see where this is going wrong?

Is this the best way to create multiple elif type statements (I want to build out more). I found `.apply()` to be quite clumsy when having many else statements.

Comment: Add a minimum reproducible example

Comment: Please make a [mre]. For specifics see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). Please also write a better title; see [ask] for tips on that.

Comment: Partial duplicate: [How do I iterate through two lists in parallel?](/q/1663807/4518341) (but not idiomatic for Pandas)

Answer (score 3):

There is a syntax error in the list comprehension. Specifically, instead of using a comma `,` to specify two lists you want to iterate through simultaneously, you should use the `zip` function, which returns a combined list of tuples.

```py
names_df['Surname'] = [
    'MISSING' if i != '' and j == '' else j
    for i, j in zip(names_df['Name Entry 1'], names_df['Name Entry 2'])
]
```

Regarding your second question, what you are doing *works*, but becomes difficult to understand as you add more conditions. If you want to use `apply`, you could create a function that handles some of the logic.

```py
def determine_surname(row):
    if row['Name Entry 1'] != '' and row['Name Entry 2'] == '':
        return 'MISSING'
    # Add more conditions as needed
    else:
        return row['Name Entry 2']

names_df['Surname'] = names_df.apply(determine_surname, axis=1)
```

Comment: Hi zip is an option here, but why should you split the two series, if you later want to combine them again? But the second option looks good!

Comment: You're right. I used `zip` since I wanted to keep it as similar to the original code as possible, especially since the syntax error came from a misunderstanding of how to iterate through two lists. I figured this was more important than efficiency. I see your solution offers a better method of doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your original code after `in` creates a tuple of two pandas series. So what Python tries to do with that, is to iterate your loop two times and it can't assign a series to two variables, since the length of the series is most likely not two.

But you can do what you intended with a minimal change in your code as follows:

```
names_df['Surname'] = [
    'MISSING' if i != '' and j == '' else j 
    for idx, i, j in names_df[['Name Entry 1', 'Name Entry 2']].itertuples()
]
```

To be honest, I wouldn't do it this way but instead rather prefer to use the `.apply` method to perform a function row by row like this:

```
names_df['Surname'] = names_df.apply(
    lambda row: 'MISSING' if row["Name Entry 1"] != '' and row["Name Entry 2"] == '' else row["Name Entry 2"], 
    axis="columns"
)
```

Example:

```
names_df = pd.DataFrame({
        "Name Entry 1": ["Miller", "Smith", "", "Parker", ""], 
        "Name Entry 2": ["Miller", "Smith", "Johnson", "", ""]
    }
)
```

For both versions this yields:

| id | Name Entry 1 | Name Entry 2 | Surname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Miller | Miller | Miller |
| 1 | Smith | Smith | Smith |
| 2 |  | Johnson | Johnson |
| 3 | Parker |  | MISSING |
| 4 |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0):

Using a random init, below:

```
choices = ['xyz', '']
rng = np.random.default_rng(25)
rng2 = np.random.default_rng(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':rng.choice(choices, 10), 'col2':rng2.choice(choices, 10)})
```

See the pandas way to do this (recommended):

```
df['new_col'] = df['col2'] # else statement
df.loc[(df['col1'] != "") & (df['col2'] == "" ),['new_col']] = 'MISSING' # if statement
```

OR you can correct your approach, you need to use `zip`:

```
df['new_col'] = ['MISSING' if i != '' and j == '' else j for i, j in zip(df['col1'], df['col2'])]
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2  new_col
0       xyz      xyz
1  xyz  xyz      xyz
2                   
3  xyz  xyz      xyz
4  xyz       MISSING
5  xyz       MISSING
6       xyz      xyz
7  xyz       MISSING
8  xyz  xyz      xyz
9  xyz       MISSING
```

Comment: With Pandas, it's cleaner to use [`.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html), as well as `.eq()` and `.ne()`: `names_df['Surname'] = names_df['Name Entry 2'].mask(names_df['Name Entry 1'].ne('') & names_df['Name Entry 2'].eq(''), 'MISSING')`